# JAVA+ Spring Edit SOAP request Message

Tags: xml, spring, soap, jaxb, soaphandler

i'm developing soap app using Spring + SOAP+JAXB+XSD

i want to add the namespace to the soap request `xml`

**My Existing request**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:res="http://WSInfo.co.in/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
  <res:WSRequest>
     <res:ID>9999999</res:ID>
     <res:NAME>JOHN</res:NAME>
     <res:MOBILE>9876543210</res:MOBILE>
     <res:EMAIL>john@gmail.com</res:EMAIL>
  </res:WSRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**My Expected request**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:res="http://WSInfo.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
  <res:WSRequest xmlns:res="http://WSInfo.com">
       <res:ID>9999999</res:ID>
     <res:NAME>JOHN</res:NAME>
     <res:MOBILE>9876543210</res:MOBILE>
     <res:EMAIL>john@gmail.com</res:EMAIL>
      </res:WSRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

if you see the expected request i want to add the below

```
<res:WSRequest xmlns:res="http://WSInfo.com">
```

My Endpoint class

```
@Endpoint
public class MyEndpoint 
{
private static final String TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://WSInfo.co.in/"";

@PayloadRoot(localPart = "WSRequest", namespace = TARGET_NAMESPACE)
public @ResponsePayload WSResponse getwsDetails(@RequestPayload WSRequest request) throws Exception
{
WSResponse response =new WSResponse();
//logic goes here
    return response;
    }
}
```

Please advise on how to alter the request `xml` with namespace

Both works, but if i want to test the service using `SoapUI` assertions fails as the request and response should have the same namespace. In my case the request envelop header has the namespace and not the `res:WSRequest`

Appreciate if you could help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why? The first works as well as the second I don't see the problem with it.

Comment: @Deinum: see my updated comments.

Comment: Then fix your assertions not the code, your assertions are wrong. We are using the same setup without problems.